# regression controversies

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, self-study

How can I test the relationship between my independent variable (in my case Price-Earnings ratio) and dependant variable (value of market deals), if I have a wide range of values of deals (400 deals with value from 10 mln up to 20 bn).

The economic logic here to test the hypothesis - is it true that low Price Earnings Ratios stimulate the deals (the low the ratio more value of deals we should have).

Thanks a lot to everybody who can help